# Would lots of idle clients cause a "service too busy" exception?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service that has an instance mode of Single and a concurrency mode of Multiple. I have the following code:

```
    public static ICmsDataServiceWcf data
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session != null && HttpContext.Current.Session["DataService"] == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("DataService", GetDataService());
            }

            if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session != null && HttpContext.Current.Session["DataService"] != null)
            {
                return (ICmsDataServiceWcf)HttpContext.Current.Session["DataService"];
            }
            return GetDataService();
        }
    }

    private static ICmsDataServiceWcf GetDataService()
    {
        string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["service_url"];
        EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress(url);

            var binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None);

            CachedWebServiceChannelFactory<ICmsDataServiceWcf> cf = new CachedWebServiceChannelFactory<ICmsDataServiceWcf>(binding, endPoint);

            var channel = cf.CreateChannel();

            return channel;
    }
```

The idea is that every client gets their own WCF client which only blocks for their requests and I don't have to suffer the overhead of creating/destroying clients multiple times.

Recently I have been getting some "service too busy" exceptions. Most of these clients are sat idle most of the time. Does an idle client still consume resources on the server? Is its instance persisted somehow server side?

Can anyone see a reason why this could cause issues? (Except for the memory wastage of letting lots of clients sit around until sessions get abandoned - I'm looking at using a pool of clients and periodically culling inactive/errored ones.)

Thanks,

Joe

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I've implemented my own proxy - not sure if that would have any impact:

```
public class CachedWebServiceProxy<T> : RealProxy
{
    private Type _typeOfProxy;
    public object _channel;
    public CachedWebServiceProxy(Type typeOfProxy, object channel)
        : base(typeOfProxy)
    {
        _typeOfProxy = typeOfProxy;
        _channel = channel;
    }
    public override System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage Invoke(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage msg)
    {
        try
        {
            var methodCall = msg as IMethodCallMessage;
            var methodInfo = methodCall.MethodBase as MethodInfo;
            object result = null;
    // Caching code removed
                result = methodInfo.Invoke(_channel, methodCall.Args);
            return new ReturnMessage(result, null, 0, methodCall.LogicalCallContext, methodCall);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Throw the actual error fro mthe webservice
            if (ex is TargetInvocationException && ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                throw ex.InnerException;
            }
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a `ChannelFactory` for each channel, throwing out the factory and then holding on to the channel, you might want to try creating the `ChannelFactory` (this is the expensive piece of work), and then instantiating a `Channel` each time you want to use it.

Taking and holding a channel is not the best practice - you should create, use, close and dispose. It's like holding a database connection - it won't be disposed unless you explicitly get rid of it.

```
private CachedWebServiceChannelFactory<ICmsDataServiceWcf> factory;

public ICmsDataServiceWcf GetDataService()
{
    if (factory == null) // or factory needs rebuilding
    {
        string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["service_url"];
        EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress(url);
        var binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None);

        factory = new CachedWebServiceChannelFactory<ICmsDataServiceWcf>
            (binding, endPoint);
    }

    return factory.CreateChannel();
}
```

and to force the close & dispose, wrap this method in a `using`

```
using (var client = GetDataService())
{
    // do stuff
} // client will be disposed upon reaching the end of the using block
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I'll do some benchmarking tomorrow and then vote as best answer. Also - would you say that what I've referenced in my answer would be a bad solution and I shouldn't use it? Thanks, Joe.

Comment: I don't know if I'd go so far as saying it is a 'bad' solution, but if you are creating a lot of connections then it's definitely best practice to close them as soon as you are done with them.

Comment: Ok thanks, the main issue that I have is that I have been brought in on a project where everything is based around the property above and the other developer has done lots of things like this:

helper.data.WcfCall(123);
helper.data.OtherWcfCall("foo");

I guess that I'll just have to tell him to fix his code.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/archive/2007/05/07/wcf-client-channel-pool-improved-client-performance.aspx which looks like exactly what I need.

Comment: It seems a bit flakey